# I have 4 dropdown and I want to hide them when page loads and then whenever add button is clicked then one dropdown should appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0">
    <h3>Co-Editors</h3>
</div>
<p class="hide_editor" id="show_editor1">
    <label for="subject_primary">Co-Editor 1:</label>
    <select name='F_co_author1' id="co_author1" onchange="LoadExperts();">
       <option value=''>No Coauthor 1</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p class="hide_editor" id="show_editor2">
    <label for="subject_primary">Co-Editor 2:</label>
    <select name='F_co_author2' id="co_author2" onchange="LoadExperts();">
        <option value=''>No Coauthor 2</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p class="hide_editor" id="show_editor3">
    <label for="subject_primary">Co-Editor 3:</label>
    <select name='F_co_author3' id="co_author3" onchange="LoadExperts();">
        <option value=''>No Coauthor 3</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p class="hide_editor" id="show_editor4">
    <label for="subject_primary">Co-Editor 4:</label>
    <select name='F_co_author4' id="co_author4" onchange="LoadExperts();">
        <option value=''>No Coauthor 3</option>
    </select>
</p>

<button id='show_add_button' type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="display: block;">Add Co-Editor</button>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> // for loading the co-editors

//hide co-editors
$(".hide_editor").hide();

//show co-editor
$("#show_add_button").on("click", function () {
//$('#show_editor1').show();

// $('#show_editor2').show();
});
</script>
```

here are four dropdowns which are hidden when the page loads but now when I click on the add button it should show only the first dropdown.

Again I click on the add button then the second dropdown should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should solve your problem. Please note that the jQuery's return behavior is different than javascript's.

```
$("#show_add_button").on("click", function() {
   $('.hide_editor').each(index => {
    const current =$('.hide_editor')[index];
    if(current.style.display === 'none') {
        current.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I also recommend hiding the dropdowns using CSS. @jay

Answer (score 0):

when you are using  jQuery stick to it, it gives better way to achieve that goal.
much cleaner and easily understandable.

```
 $("#show_add_button").on("click", () => {

    $(".hide_editor")
                    .first()
                    .removeClass("hide_editor");

 });
```